# iBeacons changes to the framework in iOS 10.x

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Swift 3.0 iOS 10.x

I am revisiting the world of iBeacons after initially looking at the technology, but seem to have come across a significant change in the way the framework seems to work in iOS 10.x; although maybe I am simply losing my mind.

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beacons.count == 0 {
        return
    }
```

This method as I understood it previously returned an array of beacons.

Which it still does, only it returns an array with a single element only each time. Sure it continues to find all the beacons within range, but fails to scope them all when scanning returning as soon as it finds one it would appear?

Is there a parameter I need set here or something perhaps?

Comment: I am unaware of any intended API change, so I suspect this is simply a test setup issue.   Are you saying that you have more than one beacon visible but you always only get one in a callback?  Do the beacons have different identifiers?

Comment: Yes, I have two beacons. Both are visible, but when the callback fires I see only one of the beacons in the array, than it fires again and I see the second. Yes they have different UUIDs and different major/minor numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ranging beacons with two different ProximityUUIDs, you must set up two different `CLBeaconRegion` objects for each ProximityUUID, then start ranging for each.

You will get one ranging callback per second for *each* `CLBeaconRegion` you are ranging.  And the callback will have a reference to both the `CLBeaconRegion` and an array of the `CLBeacon` objects detected for that region.

Because you have one beacon per region, what you are seeing where there is on beacon per callback is expected.  This is how the API has worked since iOS 7.

Comment: Ok, so its normal behaviour. Sadly the beacons I have are too old to reconfigure it seems, so I am stuck with multiple regions 4 now. Thanks for coming back to me and clarifying this.